# create an empty index, unassigned shards occur in ES 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch

As is shown in the picture，when I create an empty index there are unassigned shards:
[image]

what is the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the output you get from `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/recovery?v'` ?

Comment: I have found that there are four files  in the folder of `elasticsearch-2.3.3`:java_pid5138.hprof、java_pid10185.hprof、java_pid23054.hprof、java_pid23087.hprof.Each size of the four files is more than 800Mb.

Comment: Those are heap dumps that have been created because your ES server crashed four times.

Comment: What about the output of the _cat/recovery command?

Comment: there are information of other indexs,no information of `testindex`.

Comment: What does your ES logs tell you when you start your cluster?

Comment: `Cluster health, cluster stats and indices stats operations are blocked`

Comment: You probably have Shield installed and the license expired. Possible?

Comment: yes,I installed license and Shield plugins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121315/discussion-between-yao-pan-and-val).

Comment: The Shield plugin is not free, you either need to uninstall Shield or purchase a license otherwise your cluster won't start anymore

Comment: @Val that's incorrect information. The cluster will start but from monitoring point of view it will have reduced functionality. Check Shield's documentation about this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/2.3/license-management.html#license-expiration

Comment: Ok, "won't start" was a bit overshot, agreed. Thanks for pointing it out @AndreiStefan